# Ajaxupload.js how to pass query param to ashx file asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ashx

Hi i have been trying to pass a param to my ashx page for ages

Thank you in advance

I'm currently using this setup

[upload](http://engthunder.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/uploading-file-using-jquery-with-generic-handler-ashx/)

its using

jQuery there is a plugin from Andris Valums
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ you

code sample

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        var customerID = getURLParameter("id");   
        new AjaxUpload('#UploadButton', {
            action: 'UploadHandler.ashx',
            data: { "customerID":"44455" },
            onComplete: function (file, response) {


                $('#UploadStatus').html("<div class=success>file has been uploaded sucessfully</div>");
                $("#UploadButton").hide();
            },
            onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
                if (!(ext && /^(jpg|png)$/i.test(ext))) {
                    alert('Invalid File Format.');
                    return false;
                }
                //$('#UploadStatus').html("Uploading...");              
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

html side

```
<input type="button" id="UploadButton" class="btnReg charcoal" value="Upload Image" />
```

ashx side

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DownloadedFiles");
        customerID = context.Request.QueryString["customerID"];

        //Uploaded File Deletion
        if (context.Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
        {
            string filePath = folderPath + "//" + context.Request.QueryString[0].ToString();
            deleteIMG(filePath, context.Request.QueryString[0].ToString());
        }
        //File Upload
        else
        {
            //check if directory exist if not create one
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Files[0].FileName);
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.Files[0].FileName);

            if (context.Request.Files[0].FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") != -1)
            {
                fileName = context.Request.Files[0].FileName.Remove(0, context.Request.Files[0].FileName.LastIndexOf("\\")).ToLower();
            }

            fileName = GetUniqueFileName(fileName, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DownloadedFiles/"), ext).ToLower();

            string location = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DownloadedFiles/") + fileName + ext;
            context.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(location);            

            context.Response.Write(fileName + ext);
            context.Response.End();            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has been a while since i used it, but i think it does a POST and to be able to read those parameters in your handler you need to read them from

```
context.Request.Params["paramname"]
```